# Paste Special Method of Range class failed error while trying to save worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a worksheet data and save it in a new worksheet without copying the underlying formulas from the original sheet(shtAnalysis). I'm unable to do that as I'm getting error:

> Paste Special Method of Range class failed

at the line 
`wsPaste.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.

```
Public Sub PrepareFileAttachment()
    Application.CalculateFull
    Dim wrkBook As Workbook, wsPaste As Worksheet
    Dim Path As String
    Set wrkBook = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsPaste = wrkBook.Worksheets(1)
    Path = "C:\RandomPath" & "\" & "Report" & Format(Now, "mmddyyyy")
    shtAnalysis.Copy
    wsPaste.Activate
    wsPaste.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    shtControl.Range(GENERATED_FILENAME).Value = Path & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[Avoid the Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and the `Used.Range`, thus, change these lines:

```
shtAnalysis.Copy
wsPaste.Activate
wsPaste.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

To these:

```
shtAnalysis.Copy
wsPaste.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The original code is trying to copy the whole worksheet `shtAnalysis`, but is allowed to paste it only in the `UsedRange`, which is something that VBA does not like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this does not work. This copies the original content to a different file with the formulas and pasted the text "wsPaste.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues" in a new workbook.

Comment: @Karam - you probably did something wrong, because if you replaced exactly as mentioned, then the word `UsedRange` could not be on the text as far as it would not exist in the code. Try to restart your PC and give it a new try.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try

```
Public Sub PrepareFileAttachment()
    Application.CalculateFull
    Dim wrkBook As Workbook, wsPaste As Worksheet
    Dim openedWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim Path As String
    Set openedWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set wrkBook = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsPaste = wrkBook.Worksheets(1)
    Path = "C:\RandomPath" & "\" & "Report" & Format(Now, "mmddyyyy")
    openedWorkbook.Sheets("shtAnalysis").Copy
    wsPaste.Activate
    wsPaste.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    shtControl.Range(GENERATED_FILENAME).Value = Path & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```